# Getting Error messages while doing apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

When I do `sudo apt-get update` this is the output that I get.

```
Hit:1 https://deb.termius.com squeeze InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                               
Err:3 http://qa.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                       
  Could not resolve 'qa.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Err:5 http://qa.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                               
  Could not resolve 'qa.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://qa.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                             
  Could not resolve 'qa.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                            
Get:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease [7,343 B]                                                                            
Get:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [10.4 kB]                                                                            
Hit:10 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                  
Ign:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                         
Get:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli focal InRelease [10.4 kB]                                                                      
Err:14 https://releases.librevault.com/debian focal InRelease                                                                                        
  521   [IP: 172.67.202.232 443]
Ign:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                 
Err:17 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release                                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                               
Get:20 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease [2,536 B]                                           
Get:21 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,441 B]                                                                           
Err:22 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:18 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://releases.librevault.com/debian/dists/focal/InRelease  521   [IP: 172.67.202.232 443]
E: The repository 'https://releases.librevault.com/debian focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I looked up for solutions online, most of those questions were outdated versions of Ubuntu, but I am currently running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (End of life-April 2030). Why am I getting these errors? I tried some others solutions online, but one of them only made more errors than already existed. How do I solve this problem? Or how can I remove certain package links from the apt source list if not solve it?

Comment: You have many added PPA and unsolvable items in the sources list. They need to be removed.

Comment: How do I remove them?

Comment: Moreover focal is actual release, not an old-release.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: You (the human) made changes to your package sources (changing repositories, adding PPAs). Those changes are causing your problems. Restore the original package sources that came with your Ubuntu system -- @N0rbert provided an excellent link to help you. Use it.

Comment: Thanks to @N0rbert I solved the problem from the link provided. i opened up `software-properties-gtk` and unchecked `ppa…` and `releases.librevault…` hopefully it doesn’t crash any software but this seems to have solved the problem, now when I `sudo apt update` I don’t get any errors. The link I followed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories